# Yii2, Model find() with custom attribute

Tags: yii2

I want to pull the model data with custom attribute that assigned in a function in model.

Example)

```
class Test extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%test}}';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        //....
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'first_name' => 'First Name',
            'last_name' => 'Last Name',
        ];
    }

    public function getFullName()
    {
        $fullName = $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
        return $fullName;
    }
}



Test::find().with('fullName') => it doesn't work
```

How can I get all the data with fullname attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*with* is for [relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data). You can get *fullname* attribute just by calling `$model->fullName`. Actually *fullName* is not an attribute, yii2 utilise php's **magic method** `__get()` to get it from `getFullName()` method.

**Example:**

```
$model = Test::findOne($id);
echo $model->fullName;
```

**Example 2:**

```
$models = Test::find()->all();
foreach($models as $model)
{
    echo $model->fullName;
}
```

Also consider using of [fields/extraFields](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#fields) methods if you want use your models [as arrays](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-arrayabletrait.html#toArray%28%29-detail) instead of objects

Comment: Yes I know the magic method, but I need a list of model, collection. In that case, do I need to use loop to inject that firstName?

Comment: yes, you need to loop through list, to get `fullName` for each model